# signal SIGABRT from timeIntervalSince1970?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have a sound object that when played, it gets a timestamp set so that my application can prevent similar sounds from being played ontop of each other... The play method simply does:

```
self.timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

For some bizarre reason, I am experiencing this intermittently crashes my application when testing on an iPhone6...

malloc: *** error for object 0x1742059b0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list

I am not sure 1) why this crash would happen, and 2) what can I do to prevent it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is timestamp NSTimeInterval? I don't see it defined. Copying and pasting code is better than a screenshot

Comment: yes...  @property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timestamp;

Comment: I believe it needs to be @property (nonatomic, retain) ... try that

Comment: uhh.. nooo...  NSTimeInterval is a typedef for a double.

Comment: The crash is purely diagnostic. The problem has occurred elsewhere; some object (perhaps `self`?) has already been released. Turn on NSZombies to try to track it down.

Answer (score -1):

If NSTimeInterval (AKA a double), the property attributes should be nonatomic (depending on if you want pseudo-thread safety) and assign. Retain/Strong/Weak/Copy are used for object types. Primitives such as BOOL and float/double/int etc. should be assign. Hope this helps!

Comment: "assign" is the default behavior, and therefore unnecessary to declare.  This answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @patrick you are absolutely correct, my mistake! By chance are you accessing the timeStamp property on another thread? The value may be fudged up when working with it if your using nonatomic right?

Comment: Ah.. Actually, yes a lot of sounds are played asynchronously so, that could be it.  Thank you for suggesting that...